# Accidentall CHMOD 755 -R in home user

Tags: permissions, home, system-recovery

I was installing LAMP and I accidentally "chmoded" with -R my hole home user folder.... (`sudo chmod 755 /home/user -R`) but now my desktop themes won't load... I'm Using the Mate version of Debian Jessie... How to get things back to normal? or what's the normal chmod config for my hole home user folder?

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Does the X server start?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a simple way to undo what you have done.  The standard response is to recover everything from your last backup - but not everyone has backups.

The only other option I am aware of is to fix the permissions manually.  That means you need to know what the original permissions were.

You could create a new user, switch to that user, set up the software and themes you want to use, and then compare the permissions on the files in the new user directory with the permissions of the files in the old one, and fix the old one.

Comment: If I reformat my pc and mount that home partition again without erasing off course the files will still have their permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand that - but you've changed the permissions of the files in the filesystem, on the disk.  Those changes are permanent.  You can modify them again, but you can't undo them without reverting to a backup.

Comment: Can you or anyone else check their .theme folder and files permissions for me? aparently thats the only thing is not working

Comment: You may have broken other things, you just haven't found them yet - if you have a `.ssh` directory, then the permissions you've set are now leaving the content at risk, for example.

Comment: @EightBitTony the contents of the `.ssh` directory are ignored if they have the wrong permissions. In particular the authorized keys are.

Comment: I already figured that out... but since is home directory I can just change the permissions one by one if I need to... If you have a better solution I'll be glad to hear it, coz at this point I see no other way :D

Comment: @JoãoGeraldoNeto you have two options, recover from backup, or manually fix the permissions as explained in my answer.  I've given you one method you can do to find out what the permissions should be.

Comment: @EightBitTony Thanks mate... I don't have a Backup so I guess I'm going to create another user here when I get the time... Thanks!

Comment: I have a possible solution maybe... Let me share my thoughts and you can tell me if those would work... I have an NTFS mounted here... I could copy all files to that... Far as I know NTFS don't have permissions what so ever... then I could do another user and then copy the ntfs files to that new user home... Could this be a good idea?

Comment: No.  Comments aren't for troubleshooting.  I suggest we end this here and you raise another question if you find something you want to do that doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean? open another same question?

Comment: I just wanna know if my solution would work for this same problem... so why opening a new question to the same problem? didn't follow you there mate... Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

There's no miracle recipe to restore permissions, other than restoring from a backup. But fortunately for you permissions in a typical home directory are typically not very diverse.

- Most regular files should have permission `rw-r--r--` (644) if you don't mind that other users can read them, or `rw-------` (600) if they're private.
- Directories should have permission `rwxr-xr-x` (755) if you don't mind that other users can access files in them, or `rwx------` (700) if you want all the files in them to be private.
- If you need to work with other users on the same machine, you might need to give them access via groups or ACL, but you'd know about that.
- The `.ssh` directory needs to be more restrictive. The simple thing is to make it fully private.
- Files that you want to execute need to be made executable. These are far in between unless you have software installed in your home directory.

Starting from everything in mode 755, this should mostly fix things:

```
find ~ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + -type f -exec chmod -x {} +
chmod +x ~/bin/*
chmod go= ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/*
```

Comment: depending on the distro, `660` or `640` may be more appropriate for private files than `600` .  e.g. debian creates each user with their own group (with the same groupname as the username).  similarly, `770` or `750` for directories rather than `700`.  (obviously, excluding things like ~/.ssh because `ssh` is rightfully very strict about directory and file permissions for its config files).

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found a solution here... Copy All Files to a NTFS partition... Format or Create another User and Copy back the files you need to the new system or the new user account... Done...